# How can I improve the structure of my code to minimize the need for multiple null checks and satisfy my linter?

Tags: python

This is my result class that I use in a parser I am writing:

```
@dataclass
class NodeResult:
    was_successful: bool
    tokens: Optional[List[Token]] = field(default_factory=list)
    node: Union[ExpressionNode, TermNode, FactorNode, None] = None
    error_message: str = ""
```

In my program, I have a bunch of functions for parsing different kinds of tokens so:

- `parse_tokens_for_expression`
- `parse_tokens_for_term`
- `parse_tokens_for_factor`

And each of these functions returns a `NodeResult` object.

My first question is: is there a way to have fields of a class conditionally depend on each other?

In my class, if `tokens` has a value then so will `node` but `error_message` will not have a value (or it will still have its default value). However, if `error_message` has a value, then `tokens` and `node` will both not have values.

Is there a way that I can communicate this to Python?

A common problem that arises is that I have to check if a certain field `is not None` even if I know it should have a value. Otherwise, my linter will complain.

Here's an example:

```
term_node_result = parse_tokens_for_term(tokens)

if not term_node_result.was_successful:
    return term_node_result

# Here, I know that term_node_result.node will be a TermNode but my linter doesn't
# so I add this line

if not isinstance(term_node_result.node, TermNode):

    UNEXPECTED_TYPE = str(type(term_node_result.node))
    return report_error(unexpected_type=UNEXPECTED_TYPE)

expression_node = ExpressionNode(term_node_result.node)
```

Is there a way I can restructure my code so that I don't have to do this every time?
If you are kind and need to see more: [Source file](https://github.com/8SIXSect/SmallPythonCalculator/blob/main/main.py)

Comment: You generally don’t need verbose error checks with detailed error types, messages, and supporting functions for things that should never happen; just `assert isinstance(term_node_result.node, TermNode)`. As for actually improving the types: it’s not clear to me what the `tokens` field means, but it looks like `NodeResult` should be replaced with a `@dataclass class NodeFailure: error_message: str`, where `parse_tokens_for_term` returns a much more specific `Union[TermNode, NodeFailure]`, which you then check with `match` or `isinstance` to determine success. Not as clean as real sum types, but

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can communicate this to Python?

You could add a [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.__post_init__) method that performs the necessary validations.  E.g:

```py
import pytest
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class Token:
    pass

class ExpressionNode:
    pass

class TermNode:
    pass

class FactorNode:
    pass

@dataclass
class NodeResult:
    was_successful: bool
    tokens: list[Token]|None = field(default_factory=list)
    node: ExpressionNode | TermNode | FactorNode | None = None
    error_message: str = ""

    def __post_init__(self):
      if self.error_message:
        if (self.tokens or self.node):
          raise ValueError("NodeResult may not have both a node and an error message")
      elif not (self.tokens and self.node):
        raise ValueError("NodeResult must have both node and tokens")


def test_invalid_error_message_with_node():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        NodeResult(was_successful=False, error_message="test error", node=ExpressionNode())


def test_invalid_node_without_tokens():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        NodeResult(was_successful=True, node=ExpressionNode())

def test_valid_node():
    NodeResult(was_successful=True, node=ExpressionNode(), tokens=[Token()])

def test_valid_error_message():
    NodeResult(was_successful=False, error_message="test error")
```

All the tests defined in the above example pass successfully:

```
$ pytest -v noderesult.py
noderesult.py::test_invalid_error_message_with_node PASSED                                                                                          [ 25%]
noderesult.py::test_invalid_node_without_tokens PASSED                                                                                              [ 50%]
noderesult.py::test_valid_node PASSED                                                                                                               [ 75%]
noderesult.py::test_valid_error_message PASSED                                                                                                      [100%]
```